# Oracle Apex - changing button text and IR column headers on the fly from lookup table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oracle, apex

Apex 18.1 (soon migrating to 21)

Oracle DB 12.1

Hello, I'm hoping for some help in finding a solution for translating Apex page Button text and also Interactive Report column headings on the fly.

I have a solution for translating prompts/labels using Apex shortcuts, HTML templates and functions, but this does not work for the above (happy to explain that in further detail).

The report language translations are stored in a lookup table and I will need to interrogate that in the code.

I am hoping for an Ajax/Javascript/JQuery type solution that I can call from page 0, but I have little experience in this so any pointers would be very gratefully received.

Please note that I am not looking to use the Apex standard translation method as my apps run to hundreds of pages and several languages, so the export files are too large.

Thanks very much for any help,

Rhod

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.